# How to run a changepoint analysis on multiple time series with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I'm collecting time series data from Wikipedia and want to run a change-point analysis on each time series using dplyr. But when I do so I get an error saying the data need to be numeric, even though the `class` function states it is numeric. Hope you can help.

```
library(changepoint)
library(dplyr)
library(pageviews)
library(data.table)

articles <- c("Rugby_union", "Football")

foo <- function(x){article_pageviews(project = "en.wikipedia",
                                     article = x, 
            start = as.Date('2017-01-01'), 
            end = as.Date("2017-12-31")
          , user_type = "user", platform = c("mobile-web"))
    }

output<-articles %>% foo

output %>% 
  select(article, views) %>% 
  do(cpt.mean(.)) 

class(output$views)
```

Comment: What is dat.grp?

Comment: Given that you are hoping to operate in the tidyverse, I would have guessed that you would be reaching for the `purrr::map` function. However that's just from your description and the lack of any test data or solid description of an expected result, we can only guess. Please [edit] your question to make it reproducible. Then I can remove my close vote which is made because there's no quoted error message and no means of seeing hte error with a complete lack of data.

Comment: I've changed a typo, the object should be called output. The pageviews package should pull down the data to see what it looks like. I'm trying to get the number of changepoints per time series (rugby and football)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(changepoint)
library(dplyr)
library(pageviews)

articles <- c("Rugby_union", "Football")

foo <- function(x){article_pageviews(project = "en.wikipedia", article = x, 
                                     start = as.Date('2017-01-01'), 
                                     end = as.Date("2017-12-31"),
                                     user_type = "user", platform = c("mobile-web"))
}

output <- articles %>% 
  foo
df <- as.data.frame(table(output$article))
output1 <- output %>% 
  dplyr::select(article, views) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(article == df[1,1])
output2 <- output %>% 
  dplyr::select(article, views) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(article == df[2,1])
q <- floor((min(length(output1$views), length(output2$views)))/2 + 1)
cp1 <- changepoint::cpt.mean(data = output1$views, Q = q, method = "BinSeg", penalty 
= "SIC")
plot(cp1)
```

[image]

```
cp2 <- changepoint::cpt.mean(data = output2$views, Q = q, method = "BinSeg", penalty 
= "SIC")
plot(cp2)
```

[image]